# How to enable/disable Do Not Disturb from shell on Mavericks?

Tags: macos, keyboard, command-line, do-not-disturb

I would like to toggle the Do Not Disturb in the notification center with a keyboard shortcut.

I am using BetterTouchTool for some extra keyboard shortcuts but it does not support enabling/disabling the notifications in the default options.

It has an option for executing a terminal command so I'm asking here how to enable/disable Do Not Disturb from the terminal?

I found [Schedule ‘Do Not Disturb’ In OS X Mountain Lion With Automator](http://www.addictivetips.com/mac-os/schedule-do-not-disturb-in-os-x-mountain-lion-with-automator/) and I tried to run the commands but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Since you're really asking about how to get it done from a keyboard, as opposed to from the shell, you should probably change the title of the question.  Or if I'm wrong, please correct me!

Comment: Actually, never mind... I didn't realize that "betterTouchTool" requires the terminal for what you want.

Comment: I primarily asked how to do it from the shell. Doing it from the system preferences solves my case, but it's more fun to know how to do it from shell.

Comment: Gotcha, I updated my answer with the shell info.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can just setup a global keyboard shortcut for it in System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Mission Control

Or if you definitely want it from the command line, an applescript to do this (assuming you setup the keyboard shortcut to use <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>opt</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>.

Note that you still MUST setup a keyboard command in System Preferences for this to work.

Put the below script into a file, say, ~/dnd.applescript

```
ignoring application responses
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "D" using {command down, shift down, option down, control down}
end ignoring
```

Now you can run `osascript ~/dnd.applescript` from the command line to toggle your DND setting.

Screencap: 
[image: Keyboard shortcut modification in System Preferences]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. Wish there were a better way though.

Comment: Better in what way?

Comment: Not having to bind an obscure keyboard shortcut and toggle that with `osascript`.

Comment: I guess I'm asking if you mean better as in "more effective" or better as in "prettier under the covers."  Is it a practical or aesthetic wish?

Comment: Just curious, I don't have any additional suggestions either way.

Comment: I just dislike when there are ambiguous entry points to an action, it works like a charm though!

Comment: This no longer works in Mac Mojave or Catalina.

Comment: The applescript works when i run it from the script editor but not from terminal :(

Comment: Ventura 13.4.1: wasn't working at first but then I removed the "ignoring application responses" and saw that in my case I needed to enable iTerm in the Privacy & Security > Accessibility menu.

Comment: Huh.  Works for me on Ventura if I use Shift+Control+Option+Command+D.  But if I try to make the shortcut "lighter" by using Control+Option+D or Control+Option+Command+D, I can get DND to toggle only by physically using the keyboard, and not by using the script.  (Yes, I did update the AppleScript to remove the keys that I took out of the keyboard shortcut.)  --Edit-- I also had to remove the "ignore application responses" bit to get it to work from the terminal.

Answer (score 23):

You can simplify [the answer that razvanz provided](https://apple.stackexchange.com/revisions/145487/2) by using the `-currentHost` argument to the defaults command.

Enable Do Not Disturb:

> ```
> defaults -currentHost write ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.notificationcenterui doNotDisturb -boolean true
> defaults -currentHost write ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.notificationcenterui doNotDisturbDate -date "`date -u +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S +0000\"`"
> killall NotificationCenter
> ```

(via https://heyfocus.com/blog/enabling-do-not-disturb-mode/)

Disable Do Not Disturb:

> ```
> defaults -currentHost write ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.notificationcenterui doNotDisturb -boolean false
> killall NotificationCenter
> ```

Now you could easily wrap this up as a script to enable or disable "Do Not Disturb" as a script that would work on anybody's machine regardless of system preferences. Here is an example of how to do that:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -eou pipefail

# From https://heyfocus.com/enabling-do-not-disturb-mode and
# https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/145487

if [[ $(defaults -currentHost read ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.notificationcenterui doNotDisturb) -eq 0 ]]; then
  defaults -currentHost write ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.notificationcenterui doNotDisturb -boolean true
  defaults -currentHost write ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.notificationcenterui doNotDisturbDate -date "`date -u +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S +000\"`"
  killall NotificationCenter
  echo "Do Not Disturb is enabled. Run $0 to turn it off (OS X will turn it off automatically tomorrow)."
else
  defaults -currentHost write ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.notificationcenterui doNotDisturb -boolean false
  killall NotificationCenter
  echo "Do Not Disturb is disabled. Run $0 to turn it on again."
fi
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/ryangreenberg/5267f68a8e7b07ea66370b4eb5580ab9

Comment: Minor visual bug! [Noted for folks who look @ color]: 

I tried this and it sorta works.  I snoozed some notifications for 5 mins, and then turned on Do Not Disturb for Notifications, and then ran the commands under "Disable Do Not Disturb".
On the one hand, the icon remained greyed out, but on the other, it did appear to work otherwise - notifications popped up in a few minutes.

Second test: I turned on Do Not Disturb for Notifications (w/o snoozing anything), & ran the commands under "Disable Do Not Disturb".
The icon remained greyed out, but notifications popped right up.

Comment: @MatthewElvey That might be a change from Sierra to High Sierra. We probably need to find a new way to reload the menubar icon.

Comment: Dnd doesnt appear to be changed on high sierra/mojave with this solution

Comment: +1 After going down a ridiculous number of rabbit holes, this works on macOS Mojave 10.14.6. Not sure why, but I had to change the first line to `set -eu -o pipefail` to get it to work properly.

Comment: I am using Catalina. This solution will enable DND, but does not disable DND.

Comment: Just wanted to say that this answer really saved me, as the defaults of DoNotDisturb got broken (not even editable in the UI, and not functional) and the only way I found to fix them - was to re-write them using your commands/script. Cheers and thanks

Answer (score 18):

As of OS X 10.10.3, this AppleScript will toggle "Do Not Disturb." No keyboard shortcut required:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "SystemUIServer"
  key down option
  click menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
  key up option
end tell
```

You can save it as an AppleScript and run it from the terminal with `osascript DoNotDisturb.applescript`, or you can include it in a Bash script by wrapping it in in a heredoc like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
osascript <<EOD
  tell application "System Events" to tell process "SystemUIServer"
    key down option
    click menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
    key up option
  end tell
EOD
```

Comment: This means that you can also toggle `DoNotDisturb` by clicking the rightmost tiles in the menu bar while holding the `Option` key.

Comment: This no longer works on Mojave. Applescript seems to click the menu bar item as if option was not down, even though it is

Answer (score 7):

Building on answers from James and Zsolt, I've created a couple of scripts to turn on or off (not toggle) DND state. They also don't require any key bindings or machine GUID to work.

**IMPORTANT**: Please note that running these scripts for the first time may require accessibility permission for the app which runs the scripts. If you do not grant the permission in the request the <kbd>alt</kbd>/<kbd>option</kbd> button will remain pressed for the system and you will need to log out and back in to "unpress" it. This is also true for previous answers with AppleScript. If the script is edited, the permissions will need to be revoked and re-granted. Permissions are granted using:

```
System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Accessibility > Add your app
```

---

**For macOS Sierra and High Sierra it's `menu bar 1`:**

Turn Do Not Disturb *ON* (disable notifications):

```
if [[ $(plutil -convert xml1 -o - ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.notificationcenterui.*.plist | grep false) ]]; then
    osascript <<EOD
      tell application "System Events" to tell process "SystemUIServer"
        key down option
        click menu bar item 1 of menu bar 1
        key up option
      end tell
EOD
fi
```

Turn Do Not Disturb *OFF* (enable notifications):

```
if ! [[ $(plutil -convert xml1 -o - ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.notificationcenterui.*.plist | grep false) ]]; then
    osascript <<EOD
      tell application "System Events" to tell process "SystemUIServer"
        key down option
        click menu bar item 1 of menu bar 1
        key up option
      end tell
EOD
fi
```

---

**For earlier versions of macOS it's `menu bar 2`:**

Turn Do Not Disturb *ON* (disable notifications):

```
if [[ $(plutil -convert xml1 -o - ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.notificationcenterui.*.plist | grep false) ]]; then
    osascript <<EOD
      tell application "System Events" to tell process "SystemUIServer"
        key down option
        click menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
        key up option
      end tell
EOD
fi
```

Turn Do Not Disturb *OFF* (enable notifications):

```
if ! [[ $(plutil -convert xml1 -o - ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.notificationcenterui.*.plist | grep false) ]]; then
    osascript <<EOD
      tell application "System Events" to tell process "SystemUIServer"
        key down option
        click menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
        key up option
      end tell
EOD
fi
```

Comment: This no longer works on Mojave. Applescript seems to click the menu bar item as if option was not down, even though it is

Answer (score 5):

## Schedule *Do Not Disturb*

Just to add that you can also schedule Do Not Disturb from the command line to activate/deactivate each day at set times.

To set the time when DND will be *enabled*:

```
defaults -currentHost write ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.notificationcenterui dndStart -integer <start_time_in_minutes>
```

To set the time when DND will be *disabled*:

```
defaults -currentHost write ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.notificationcenterui dndEnd -integer <end_time_in_minutes>
```

***NOTE:*** replace `<start_time_in_minutes>` and `<end_time_in_minutes>` with the desired value (explained below).

---

### Example:

To schedule DND to start each day at 15:00 and to end at 18:30 do the following:

Convert 15:00 and 18:30 to minutes to get the value of `<start_time_in_minutes>` and `<end_time_in_minutes>`. That is, multiply the number of hours by 60 and add the number of minutes.

For 15:00 that would be: `15 * 60 + 0 = 900` and for 18:30 that would be: `18 * 60 + 30 = 1110`. Giving us the commands below:

```
defaults -currentHost write ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.notificationcenterui dndStart -integer 900
defaults -currentHost write ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.notificationcenterui dndEnd -integer 1110
killall NotificationCenter # 'resets' Notificatio Center so that it reads the DND change
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on James's answer, I'd also liek to point out that you can also determine if it is turned on or off. So the following turns it off, and does nothing if already off:

```
if [[ $(plutil -convert xml1 -o - ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.notificationcenterui.000-000-000-000.plist | grep false) ]]; then
    osascript <<EOD
      tell application "System Events" to tell process "SystemUIServer"
        key down option
        click menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
        key up option
      end tell
EOD
fi
```

You must substitute your own machine GUID into the filename (there is only one file there, so it's easy to figure out)

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to no longer work in Big Sur -- the file always contains `false` regardless of whether notification center is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

## Answer as of 2020-10, Version 10.15.6

https://github.com/sindresorhus/do-not-disturb-cli

After installing with
`$ npm install --global do-not-disturb-cli`

You can toggle Do Not Disturb by running
`$ dnd`

---

I was searching for a way to set an alias in my bash profile that would

1. Enable Do Not Disturb
2. Un-Hide the Dock

So now I can do

```
alias dndon='dnd on && defaults write com.apple.dock autohide -bool false && killall Dock'

alias dndoff='dnd off && defaults write com.apple.dock autohide -bool true && killall Dock'
```

Answer (score 0):

This comes up as a Google hit, so I thought I'd update it with a working, command-line, nothing-to-learn, Mavericks-friendly solution as of 2021-07-28:  https://github.com/joeyhoer/dnd.
Downloaded it and ran it and it just works, including changing icon status.  Hours of searching has ended.  My system has now improved!

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that works on Big Sur (as most answers do not):

```
brew install vitorgalvao/tiny-scripts/calm-notifications
calm-notifications on
```

Taken from this answer: https://github.com/sindresorhus/do-not-disturb/issues/9#issuecomment-765083970