# Toggle notification center's DoNotDisturb from terminal

Tags: terminal, macos, applescript, notifications

Is there any way to toggle it with i.e. osascript? I'm on Yosemite.

Comment: Does this work? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/145487/how-to-enable-disable-do-not-disturb-from-shell-on-mavericks