# How to enable/disable Do Not Disturb from shell on Mojave?

Tags: keyboard, command-line, alfred

I've searched far and wide, but obviously not enough, to find a solution for this on macOS Mojave.

I found the answers here, but they don't work on Mojave: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/303400/193408

It appears to not do anything; the Do Not Disturb toggle in the sidebar doesn't change.

Comment: Did you try the other answers there as well? What was the result?

Comment: @nohillside Hi, I added a little bit more context to my question. But yes, and nothing seems to happen when I ran any of them.

Comment: @codeforever Were you able to find any solution? I have been looking for ages as well and cannot find anything for mojave

Comment: I only have been able to use this hacky solution https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/145491/96517 so far

Comment: @Dylanthepiguy Hey, unfortunately no. The closest I got was an Alfred workflow that helped expedite things, but even that stopped working. Thanks for the link! I will give that a shot as well, though as you said it does look kind of hacky. If you find anything, post back? Cheers!

Comment: I will post back if I find anything. I can only think of one other solution: Have an applescript open the notification sidebar (by clicking the menu bar button) then click the do not disturb button, then close the notification sidebar. I won't have time to try this out anytime soon, but I'll let you know if I get it working