# macOS, can Do Not Disturb be enabled for just an hour, etc.?

Tags: do-not-disturb

By default, DND disables itself the following day.  But it would be much more useful to be able to just set it for say an hour.  As far as I can tell on macOS this is not possible.

Is there a way to turn on DND for just a short window of time such as 1 hour etc.?

I found at least one commercial app that allows this functionality, but it seems like this should be basic core functionality in the OS.  Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this?  If there is no other option than a 3rd party app I'd consider it, but I would prefer a native solution.

To be clear, this is specifically about macOS, not iOS.

Comment: You mean without using the "From ___ to: ____" option in Sys Prefs | Notification Center | Do Not Disturb?

Comment: Correct, not scheduling, but simply like you can do in iOS, DND for the next hour, for example.

Comment: @JVC make a script using tips at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/145487/how-to-enable-disable-do-not-disturb-from-shell-on-mavericks/368538#368538 and use "Script Editor.app"'s menu bar icon to access it

Comment: Thanks for the idea @ankii, that's more hassle and tweaking than I want to deal with though.

Comment: Just one time though :p but yes, dnd should be a habit, not a burden