# Apple Script runs fine, need kill switch

Tags: macos, applescript

The following script runs fine in the /etc folder and called by a plist. It basically says text when the battery is too low. This is a simplified version, the real script is much longer.

```
set Cap to (do shell script "ioreg -w0 -l | grep ExternalChargeCapable")

tell Cap to set {wallPower} to {last word of paragraph 1}
if wallPower = "Yes" then
    return 0
else
    set Pct to (do shell script "pmset -g batt | grep -Eo \"\\d+%\" | cut -d% -f1")
    if Pct ≤ 10 then
        display notification "Batterij 10%. Meteen opladen." with title "Batterij bijna leeg!" sound name "Sosumi"
        ##      delay 300
        say "Batterij 10%. Meteen opladen."
    end if
end if
```

The problem is that I haven't found a good way for a kill switch. The kill switch will be operated by a user without admin rights.

I am open to any suggestions for a kill switch.

As an example, I found [this topic](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/419207/turn-do-not-disturb-on-or-off-in-an-applescript-app-macos-catalina?newreg=ee307ee129d649de9224a4bf73bf08db) that implements a condition if "Do not disturb" is active. I inserted this in the script and it works just fine in the Script Editor itself, but once the script is copied to the /etc folder and called by a plist the execution appears to halt at this line:

```
  set statusOfDND to ¬
        (do shell script checkDNDstatusCMD) ¬
            as number as boolean
```

Not sure why, could be regional settings (I'm using Dutch whereas the original script owner uses English (US).

Comment: Since this is launched using `launchctl` and run by `launchd` you'll need you to use `launchctl` to stop, disable/unload the **Launch Agent**.  If you are going to use **Launch Agents** and **Launch Daemons**, I highly recommend you read the _manual pages_ for `launchctl`, `launchd.plist` and `launchd`.  You can read the _manual page_ for _`command`_ in **Terminal** by typing _`man command`_, then press **enter**, or **for easier reading**, just type _`command`_ and then right-click on it and select: **Open man Page**

Comment: You may also what to have a look at: [Daemons and Services Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html)

Comment: Thank you @user3439894 for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

Crossing the user session barrier is non-trivial. Typically a local host only network connection is used, such as TCP/IP or a Mach port. These are complex to set up with AppleScript.

Below are a couple of reasonable alternatives.

### File Based Flag

You could use the existence (or lack of) a file to determine how the script behaves:

- On launch, script creates an accessible file at a known path:

  `/Users/Shared/delete-to-stop-power-script.txt`
- Periodically, or via `kqueue`, the script can check the file still exists;
- On exit, the script should remove the file.

Using files makes dealing with permissions easier. Use [`chmod 0666`](https://chmodcommand.com/chmod-666/) to allow anyone to delete the file.

The access permissions of the file can be used to ensure only specific groups of users can delete the file.

### `notifyutil`

Use the lesser known [`notifyutil`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/notifyutil/) utility:

> **notifyutil** is a command-line utility for interacting with the [notify(3)](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/notify.3.html)
> notification system and the notifyd(8) server.  It may be used to post
> notifications, detect and report notifications, and to examine and set
> the state values associated with notification keys.

`notifyd` allows processes to exchange integer values across processes and user sessions. The format is deliberately simple and constrained to enforce security.

See the linked manual page and Brett Terpstra's [Quick Tip: system-wide notifications with notifyutil](https://brettterpstra.com/2012/07/04/quick-tip-system-wide-notifications-with-notifyutil/) for samples.

#### Non-polling

If you need a non-polling alternative, [Power Manager](https://www.dssw.co.uk/powermanager) can trigger scripts on battery levels, offers a [power source scripting API](https://www.dssw.co.uk/blog/2013-06-23-scripting-batteries-and-ups-on-mac-os-x/), and non-administrator users can be granted rights to cancel or stop events.

I am a software engineer involved with Power Manager, so feel free to ask me technical questions about how it works.